# Liferay Portlet prefrences

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, portlet

I'm trying to allow to Liferay's administrator to configure a Portlet.
I have created the configuration page and configuration action.

The problem is: I can save the configuration and the portlet use this configuration correctly, but I can't get this values when I enter again in configuration.

```
 <%  
     String somePreferenceKey_cfg = portletPreferences.getValue("salesMin","");
 %>
 ......
 <aui:input name="salesMin" type="text" value="<%= somePreferenceKey_cfg %>" />
```

somePreferenceKey_cfg is empty.

Somebody have any idea about what can I do?
Thanks, Iván.

Answer (score 2):

Either use:

```
PortletPreferences preferences = renderRequest.getPreferences();
String somePreferenceKey_cfg = preferences.getValue("salesMin", "default_value");
```

Or:

```
String somePreferenceKey_cfg =
    GetterUtil.getString(portletPreferences.getValue("salesMin", "default_value"));
```

to get value from preference. Also, set some default value in-case preference are not manually stored.

Answer (score 1):

How you are instantiating the portletPreferences object? Try obtaining the portletId and call PortletPreferences API of Liferay. For example:

```
PortletPreferences portletPreferences = PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil.getPortletSetup(request,portletId);
```